# Print register value with write system call assembly

Tags: assembly, stack-overflow, inline-assembly

```
.section .bss
        .lcomm stack, 4

.section .text

.globl _start
_start:
nop

movl %eip,$stack   --> How i can move ESP or any other registers value which will actually be ADDRESS , into STACK variable?

movl $4, %eax
movl $1, %ebx
movl $stack, %ecx
movl $4, %edx
int $0x80

movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80
```

Actually I want to print current ESP value using WRITE system call, as I will use this in my C program as inline assembly.

Comment: You have to convert it to a hex string first.

Comment: any Idea how i can proceed with this code?

Answer (score 1):

This GNU C/C++ code (GNU because of the style of inline assembly it uses to retrieve the current stackpointer value) will print the current value of the stackpointer (in hex)

```
static __inline__ void printESP(void) {
    static const hexdigit[] = "0123456789ABCDEF\n";
    uintptr_t SP;

    __asm__ __volatile__("mov %%esp, %0\n\t" : "=r"(SP));

    write(1, &hexdigit[SP >> 28], 1);
    write(1, &hexdigit[0xf & SP >> 24], 1);
    write(1, &hexdigit[0xf & SP >> 20], 1);
    write(1, &hexdigit[0xf & SP >> 16], 1);
    write(1, &hexdigit[0xf & SP >> 12], 1);
    write(1, &hexdigit[0xf & SP >> 8], 1);
    write(1, &hexdigit[0xf & SP >> 4], 1);
    write(1, &hexdigit[0xf & SP], 1);
    write(1, &hexdigit[16], 1);
}
```

Due to the `static __inline__`, gcc in most circumstances (except, really, if you use a function pointer) will actually not create this function but embed the code directly at the callsite.

You could construct a more elaborate piece that'd do something like:

```
static __inline__ printESP(void)
{
    static const char hexdigit[] = "0123456789ABCDEF\n";
    uintptr_t SP;
    char buf[9];

    __asm__ __volatile__("mov %%esp, %0\n\t" : "=r"(SP));

    buf[0] = hexdigit[SP >> 28];
    buf[1] = hexdigit[0xf & SP >> 24];
    buf[2] = hexdigit[0xf & SP >> 20];
    buf[3] = hexdigit[0xf & SP >> 16];
    buf[4] = hexdigit[0xf & SP >> 12];
    buf[5] = hexdigit[0xf & SP >> 8];
    buf[6] = hexdigit[0xf & SP >> 4];
    buf[7] = hexdigit[0xf & SP];
    buf[8] = hexdigit[16];
    write(1, buf, 9);
}
```

This constructs a temporary buffer on the stack and invokes the `write()` just exactly once.

The disadvantage of the second piece code is that it actually *consumes stackspace*, which means if you invoke it, say, from a function that'd overflowed its stack and/or corrupted its stackpointer, it'll crash. The trivial first one emitting the address character-by-character might still work.

Note on your initial assembly code: That's using a *global* buffer and is therefore not thread-safe; if you invoke it from multiple threads at the same time, they'll corrupt the variable and you'll get garbage. So no, I won't help "fix" that one.

General note on the approach: Personally, I think that's what debuggers are for. This specific type of runtime instrumentation (in this fashion - by printing values directly) is rather not useful; if runtime instrumentation, then better log to an in-memory trace buffer, where you can record extended information like (partial) stacktraces, thread IDs, timestamps, other register values etc. as well as just the stackpointer. Using an in-memory (ring)buffer doesn't rely on a special meaning for filedescriptor 1, and allows "contextual" information more descriptive of what's going on than a stackpointer value only.

Also, if the value doesn't have to be 100% exact, you could use [gcc builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html), `uintptr_t SP = (uintptr_t)__builtin_frame_address(0)` instead. You wouldn't need the inline assembly at all. The difference is that it'll give you the stackpointer at *entry* to the function, not the *current* one at callsite, i.e. it doesn't account for stack usage by local variables and other "temporaries".